# File name too long error with command 'stat'

Tags: bash, unix, xargs

I retrieve a booklist after seaching the python books in home directory using command

```
    find ~ -type f -iregex '.*python.*\.pdf'
```

the booklist

```
    ...
    .../Computing/Python/Beginning_Python.pdf
    .../Python/Core.Python.Applications.Programming.3rd.Edition.pdf
    .../Python/Packt.Mastering.Python.2016.4.pdf
    ...
```

I intend to check their status with command `xargs` and `stat`

```
find ~ -type f -iregex '.*python.*\.pdf' | xargs -0 stat -x
```

get error

```
 : stat: File name too long
```

How to conquer such a problem?

Comment: How many files match the regex?

Comment: there's 45 files matched @Phil

Comment: have you tried looping through the list of filenames from find, rather than piping directly to xargs? That way you could echo each filename and see if there is still an issue.

Comment: $ find ~ -type f -iregex '.*python.*\.pdf' | xargs -0 echo  works well to print all the books @Phil

Comment: @WangGaowei That's because `echo` gets one argument with a bunch of embedded newlines, rather than `echo` being called with a single newline-free argument many times.

Comment: There's no need here (as is commonly the case) to use `xargs` with `find`; just use `find ~ -type f -iregex '.*python.*\.pdf' -exec stat -x {} \+`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `-0` with `xargs`, you are also supposed to use `-print0` with `find`.